# How can I filter pull requests that are not yet approved

Tags: github

I'd like to see a list of pull requests that I'm assigned to review that are not yet approved.

I can see using the filter box which PR's I'm assigned to with

> is:open is:pr assignee:*MyId*

what can I add to reduce the list of PRs to those not yet approved? Does new approval review feature have a field name I can filter on and pair with 'NOT'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>Dec 2016: That does not seem to be available</del>
Update February 2017: The approved status is now part of the [search criteria](https://help.github.com/articles/using-search-to-filter-issues-and-pull-requests/).

> Filter pull requests that a reviewer has approved: `state:open type:pr review:approved`

You can [search based on the state of an issue or pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-based-on-the-state-of-an-issue-or-pull-request):

> You can filter pull requests based their review status (`none`, `required`, `approved`, `changes requested`, or `required`), by reviewer, and by requested reviewer.

[**type:pr review:approved**](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=type%3Apr%20review%3Aapproved&type=Issues&ref=searchresults): will Match pull requests that a reviewer has approved.

See "[**Filter pull request reviews and review requests**](https://github.com/blog/2306-filter-pull-request-reviews-and-review-requests)" (January 23d, 2017)

> To make it easier to find the pull requests that need your attention, you can now **[filter by review status](https://help.github.com/articles/filtering-pull-requests-by-review-status)** from your repository pull request index.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/22212644/7711bef8-e15f-11e6-8331-5973635cd6ee.png]

Note though that the [Pull Request API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) does not mentioned an approved state.
Nor does the [List reactions for a pull request review comment](https://developer.github.com/v3/reactions/#list-reactions-for-a-pull-request-review-comment).

Answer (score 4):

Very late answer to a stale question but thought it would be useful to clarify something.

For any criteria used in a query, you can use the `-` qualifier to signify a logical `NOT`.

As mentioned by other comments, the `review` criteria now exists. [Documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-pull-request-review-status-and-reviewer).

So you can write the following query to get all open PRs which are not approved yet:

```
is:open is:pr -review:approved
```

*(not the `-` before the `review:approved` filter)*

Answer (score 2):

Find PRs which still open (exclude draft PRs) and are not yet reviewed/approved by me:

This is what works in Sep 2023 with the Github Enterprise 3.7:

```
is:open is:pr -review:approved -is:draft -reviewed-by:MYADSID
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gitub has added some review filters recently
[image: reviews pulldown]